# Toggling Next TR

Tags: jquery, toggle

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tahirjadoon/v6FY7/

I have an example set at the above link. My requirement is a table. On tr, it has a jerk to it, and after the tr expands, their is a bounce as well, on all the browsers. How can i make it better?

html

```
<table class="table-grid">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="" id="item1" class="expandCollapse collapse">Expand 1</a></td>
        <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> 1 - 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 1 - 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 1 - 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 1 - 4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="" id="item2" class="expandCollapse collapse">Expand 2</a></td>
        <td>200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> 1 - 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 1 - 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 1 - 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 1 - 4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.table-grid {width:85%;border: 0; margin:0 0 20px 1px;border-collapse:collapse;}
.table-grid td {border: 1px solid #c3d9ee;padding:.3em 1.1em;}
.table-grid td, .table-grid td a.expand, .table-grid td a.collapse {color:#000; text-align:left;font: bold 1em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
.table-grid td a.expand { text-decoration: none; padding-left: 20px; color: red;  }
.table-grid td a.collapse { text-decoration: none; padding-left: 20px; color: green;  }
.table-grid td a.expand:hover, .table-grid td a.collapse:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(".expandCollapse").closest("tr").next("tr").toggle();

        $(".expandCollapse").click(function(){
            if ($(this).closest("tr").next("tr").is(':visible')) {
                $(this).removeClass("expand").addClass("collapse");
            }
            else{
                $(this).removeClass("collapse").addClass("expand");
            }
            $(this).closest("tr").next("tr").slideToggle("slow");
            return false;
        });
    });
```

When converted to divs, slide up and down is slow and there is no jerk/bounce.

Div example:
http://jsfiddle.net/tahirjadoon/DuHN8/

html

```
<h2 class="triggerMax" id="Item1">
    <a href="#">Item # 1</a>
</h2>
<div class="toggle_containerMax">
    <div class="block">
        <p>Text for item 1</p>
        <p>Text for item 1</p>
        <p>Text for item 1</p>
        <p>Text for item 1</p>
        <p>Text for item 1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<h2 class="triggerMax" id="Item2">
    <a href="#">Item # 2</a>
</h2>
<div class="toggle_containerMax">
    <div class="block">
        <p>Text for item 2</p>
        <p>Text for item 2</p>
        <p>Text for item 2</p>
        <p>Text for item 2</p>
        <p>Text for item 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.toggleContainerMax { width: 300px; text-align: left; font-family:Arial;font-size: 9pt; }
h2.triggerMax {
    padding: 0px; margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px; height: 46px; line-height: 46px;  font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; cursor: pointer;
    text-indent:0px; /*this to tackle common h2 style interfering with toggle*/
}
h2.triggerMax a { padding-left:40px; color: #000; text-decoration: none; display: block; }
h2.triggerMax a:active { outline: none; /* hide dotted outline in fire fox*/}
h2.triggerMax a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
.toggle_containerMax .block {
    padding: 15px 20px 10px 20px; /*--Padding of Container--*/
    position: relative;
}
h2.activeMax { background-color: yellow; }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".toggle_containerMax").hide();

    $("h2.triggerMax").toggle(function () {
        $(this).addClass("activeMax");
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("activeMax");
    });

    $("h2.triggerMax").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".toggle_containerMax").slideToggle("slow");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default TRs have display set to `table-row`, change it to `display-block` allow animate height:

```
tr{display:block}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v6FY7/4/

Comment: But then it doesn't display properly as a table.  Things dont' align correctly, etc.

Comment: ya, you need to restyle it as a table's row then. This answer is just to explain to OP weird behaviour

Comment: I like the affect here. I'll target specific tr's as suggested and then fix styling issues. Thanks.

Comment: Product has changed requirements, now they are displaying the nested content. Thanks every one for their suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why that is happening, but upgrading to `jquery 1.9.1` seems to fix the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/v6FY7/2/

It probably has something to do with the fact that `slideToggle` doesn't really work with `tr` elements.  You should probably just change this to `toggle` if you must use a `tr`.

Comment: I don't see any difference. I don't see any problem either. Using chrome.

Comment: I think the problem the OP is having is that the effects aren't running when the rows are toggled. Upgrading the version doesn't do anything, because his JS isn't written correctly for handling the animations.

Comment: In FF it works as described.  When you expand the row the contents have a weird jitter.  With 1.9.1 the jitter is gone.

Comment: @charlie But id **does** do something.  As described "after the tr expands, their is a bounce".  If you look at the original jsfiddle, expand and watch the contents, it shakes when expanded.  In the upgraded 1.9.1 version there is no shake.

Comment: I thought "How can i make it better" meant that he wanted to make the animations more fluid, as far as sliding goes. For me, there is no animation in neither your fiddle or his first one, so it seems the problem is with the animation, not the version of jQuery.

Comment: I guess there isn't a very clear question so we're getting different interpretations.

Comment: It is the bounce that i want to get out. I can't update the jquery version.

Comment: @learning... Then change to simply toggle instead of slideToggle as I suggested.  This removes the jitter.  SlideToggle doesn't really work with `tr`.

Comment: Thanks! Product has changed requirements, now they are displaying nested content. I will play with yours and @roasted suggestions later in the evening.